# Usability vs Readability of XML Result from a REST Interface

Tags: xml, rest

Morning folks,

I have a dilemma about returning certain values from my REST Service in xml, should they be readable or xml safe. Consider a value of "Jill & Bob"

**Human Readable:**

```
<ModelItem>
   <Name>Jill & Bob</Name>
</ModelItem>
```

**XML Safe:**

```
<ModelItem>
   <Name>Jill &amp; Bob</Name>
</ModelItem>
```

This becomes more of an issue if I were to return a url within my xml:

```
<ModelItem>
   <Name>Jill & Bob</Name>
   <link>http://myweb.com/showitem?id=123&order=desc</link>
</ModelItem>
```

If I then return an xml safe url, my url is no-longer a valid url:

```
<ModelItem>
   <Name>Jill & Bob</Name>
   <link>http://myweb.com/showitem?id=123&amp;porder=desc</link>
</ModelItem>
```

Comment: Use `&amp;` including a closing `;`.

Comment: Yep just updated my original post - my bad I missed that by mistake.

Comment: Not having a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "human readable" examples are not valid XML because the single `&` is not a valid XML entity.

Every client consuming correct XML must be able to understand XML entities like `&amp;` (note the `;`!) and display the correct character instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is sort of an invisible border that your data cross when serializing to or deserializing from XML. So when you want to access the value of your `<link>` element, make sure you don't search within the XML string but do a "real" deserialization (to DOM or whatever) before you access your text content. Otherwise you have to handle things like character / entity encoding yourself, which you shouldn't, because the deserializer is supposed to do this kind of things for you.